# "Error al Enviar Correo" o "Se excedió el tiempo de espera de la operación" tras tratar de enviar un tercer correo a lista de contactos

Tags: vb.net, .net

Tengo una lista de alumnos a los cuales debo enviarles correos periódicamente; los correos no deben ir a todos los destinatarios de una vez, sino uno por uno.

Logro hacer que envíe los dos primeros, pero al querer enviar el tercero me aparecen los errores:
*"Error al Enviar Correo"* o *"Se excedió el tiempo de espera de la operación"*.

Esto es siempre después del segundo correo y tarda bastante tiempo en, digamos, desbloquearse y permitir que envíe otros dos correos más.

He cambiado el Timeout y no me resuelve nada. Pareciera que se quedara en ejecución cada uno de los envíos.

Este es el código que envía el mensaje

```
Public Sub EnviarCorreo(Destinatario As String, Asunto As String, Mensaje As String)

    Try

        Using Correo As New MailMessage
            Correo.From = New MailAddress(eDir)
            Correo.Subject = Asunto
            Correo.IsBodyHtml = False
            Correo.Body = Mensaje
            Correo.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
            Correo.To.Add(Destinatario)

            Using Cliente As New SmtpClient
                Cliente.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
                Cliente.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                Cliente.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(eDir, eCon)
                Cliente.Port = ePrt
                Cliente.EnableSsl = eSSL
                Cliente.Host = eSMT
                Cliente.Timeout = 30

                Cliente.Send(Correo)
            End Using
        End Using

        bSig = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        bSig = False
        Clipboard.SetText(ex.Message)
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Enviando Correo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pudiera ser porque el orden en el que se definen MailMessage y SmtpClient es alrevés (normalmente):

```
Public Sub EnviarCorreo(Destinatario As String, Asunto As String, Mensaje As String)
    Try
        Using smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(eSMT, ePtr)
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            smtp.Credentials = New _
                System.Net.NetworkCredential(eDir, eCon)
            smtp.EnableSsl = eSSL
            smtp.Timeout = 30

            Using mailMsg As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
                mailMsg.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress(remitente)
                mailMsg.To.Add(New Net.Mail.MailAddress(Destinatario))
                mailMsg.Subject = Asunto
                mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = False
                mailMsg.Body = Asunto
                smtp.Send(mailMsg)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```